# Pairing is a bad tag and should be removed?

Tags: discussion, scope

I saw a question marked [pairing](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pairing). By its very nature, [pairing](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pairing) is an opinion-based tag and should be removed. In my opinion it should be site policy not to allow these type of questions.

Comment: Not so sure, let's have a discussion: [Should Food/Beer pairings be on topic?](http://meta.beer.stackexchange.com/q/11)

Comment: Since your objection isn't really about the tag, but the underlying questions, I'm going to ask you to join the discussion already on this topic.

Answer (score -3):

It's not necessarily opinion-based, since for wine there are strong consumption norms which wine suits which dish.

However, in my opinion, the name [pairing](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pairing) is a bit unfortunate. It should be renamed to something suggesting better, that that tag is for the questions about composing beer with dishes, maybe [consumption](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consumption) or [meal](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meal)...

Comment: Pairing is the perfect tag. It's clearly understood and represents a real area of expertise.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz when I hear that word I think of breeding...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's on you. :P

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I'm not native speaker, maybe that's the reason...